# NSPanel : double animation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nswindow

I am trying to animate an NSPanel derived window with a fade-in while sliding (moving from outside to inside the screen)
What is way to do a such animation?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never done this on my own. And while I think that sliding should be fairly enough, here's an attempt:

- You need a non-opaque window. Use `setOpaque:` and set it to NO
- The windows's content view should be layer-backed. Use `setWantsLayer:` and set to YES (at least during the animation).
- Then you can get the window's content view's layer: [[window contentView] layer]
- Animate the layers opacity using CoreAnimation techniques alongside the window's frame

Answer (score 1):

[NSViewAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSViewAnimation_Class/) can do both at once, and it works on windows, not just views.